# Tooltips for keyboard users

Tags: accessibility, title-attribute

The `title` attribute can be used on almost any HTML element, particularly hyperlinks, to provide some additional detail of the element. This is useful for screen readers, but not so much when using the keyboard to tab through elements.

I often use the **TAB** key to skip over some links in a page to avoid having to reach for the mouse. Yet the title tooltips are only visible when the mouse is hovered over the matching element.

Is this a failing of the browser, or is it something that should be accounted for in site design and implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers ought to have the option to enable tooltips on focus, but since they don't you can do it via JavaScript: [Onfocus tooltips](http://www.brothercake.com/site/resources/scripts/tooltips/).